# Como encontrar valores específicos em uma String?

Tags: java, string

Tenho que pegar o adaptador de Ethernet + o IPV4 do Windows, até ai tudo tranquilo. Executei o processo e armazenei tudo em uma String Buffer e mandei ela como retorno:

```
public String IP (String tarefa)
{           
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        Process processo = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(tarefa);
        InputStream fluxo = processo.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader lefluxo = new InputStreamReader(fluxo);

        BufferedReader bufferLeitura = new BufferedReader(lefluxo);
        String linha = bufferLeitura.readLine();

        while(linha != null)
        {
            buffer.append(linha);
            buffer.append("\n");                                
            linha = bufferLeitura.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Agora, tenho que pegar somente o adaptador de rede e o número de IP para apresentar como resultado e eu não estou conseguindo pensar em uma maneira de fazer tal coisa.

Como faço para dividir a String nas partes que eu quero? E se é possível fazer isso no **Main**?

Comment: Tentou usar expressões regulares? Eu to sem java aqui pra ver como é a string que resulta, posta ela fazendo favor.

Comment: Seria muito mais fácil colocar a string que pretendes fraccionar, o código fonte não ajuda muito, por enquanto.

Answer (score 2):

Estou considerando que você está executando `ipconfig`, para este caso. Em minha máquina ao executar o seu código este foi o retorno do seu código:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter VirtualBox:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bd60:54a2:6750:bd19%17
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.189.25
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::582:c128:49ba:f141%2
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D19E2903-0FED-491B-A030-6B12CB30F3C3}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:2cd2:ee13:42fb:b44b
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2cd2:ee13:42fb:b44b%19
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::

Tunnel adapter isatap.{0D84F8B4-2DA0-4513-9AF4-700EDF9BA40F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Uma forma, como já dito, é usando expressões regulares. Neste caso precisarei usar duas:

- uma para achar o adaptador, considerando linhas que começam com `Ethernet adapter`, algo assim:

```
(Ethernet adapter )(\w*)
```

- e outra para recuperar o IP propriamente dito, considerando os que tenham `IPv4 Address`, algo deste tipo:

```
(IPv4 Address)(\. |\: )*(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|$)){4})
```

Criei uma entidade apenas para ficar mais fácil de montar o retorno, dei o nome de `NetworkInfo` e ela assim:

```java
public class NetworkInfo {

    private String ip;
    private String adapter;

    // getters e setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Adapter: %s | IP: %s", this.getAdapter(), this.getIp());
    }

}
```

A partir do resultado gerado pelo seu método `IP`, iremos agora na string resultante (aquela lá em cima) procurar pelo conteúdo que nos interessa. Para não ser necessário fazer *match* em linhas sem conteúdo estou desconsiderando-as (`if (linha.trim().length() > 0)`). Veja abaixo exemplo de método que processa a `String` gerada por `IP` (`ipconfig` no meu exemplo):

```java
private static final Pattern ADAPTER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(Ethernet adapter )(\\w*)");
private static final Pattern IPV4_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(IPv4 Address)(\\. |\\: )*(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\\.|$)){4})");

public List<NetworkInfo> listNetworkAdapters(final String task) throws Exception {
    final List<NetworkInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();

    String ip = null;
    String adapter = null;

    final String ipconfig = this.ipconfig(task); // "ipconfig" é o seu método "IP".

    final String[] lines = ipconfig.split("\n");

    for (final String line : lines) {
        if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
            final Matcher adapterMatcher = ADAPTER_PATTERN.matcher(line);
            if (adapterMatcher.find()) {
                adapter = adapterMatcher.group(2); // recuperamos apenas o nome, o 2º grupo da regex
            } else {
                final Matcher ipMatcher = IPV4_PATTERN.matcher(line);
                if (ipMatcher.find()) {
                    ip = ipMatcher.group(3); // aqui recuperamos apenas o IP, o 3º grupo da regex
                }
            }

            if (ip != null && adapter != null) {
                final NetworkInfo info = new NetworkInfo();
                info.setIp(ip);
                info.setAdapter(adapter);
                result.add(info);

                ip = null;
                adapter = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Aqui, como pode perceber, estou criando um *array* para cada linha retornada divindo a `String` pela quebra de linha, `\n`. Depois disto tentamos procurar os padrões que precisamos e quando temos uma dupla formada, criamos uma `NetworkInfo` e adicionamos ao retorno.

A partir das informações obtidas pelo `ipconfig` acima, foram gerados dois objetos `NetworkInfo` como retorno pelo método `listNetworkAdapters`. Fazendo a impressão deles assim:

```java
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final List<NetworkInfo> result = new IPConfig().listNetworkAdapters("ipconfig");
    for (final NetworkInfo info : result) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }
}
```

O resultado gerado foi este:

```
Adapter: VirtualBox | IP: 169.254.189.25
Adapter: Ethernet | IP: 192.168.1.100
```

Lembro que o exemplo é considerando apenas este retorno, caso o seu padrão seja diferente, atualize a sua pergunta com o resultado que obtém.